# WakeLock Acquisition Issue In Broadcast Receiver

Tags: android

I developing an application where i need a broadcast receiver to generate notifications 
on receiving messages from GCM push.

The code i am using refuses to compile, stating that

```
   "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method acquire() from
  the type PowerManager.Wakelock"
```

The IDE (eclipse) now suggests i should

```
 remove argument to match "acquire()"
```

However when i do that, the next error shown is:

```
 The method acquire(long) in the type PowerManager.WakeLock is not applicable        
  for the arguements(Context)....
```

The code for the broadcast receiver is :

```
   private final BroadcastReceiver mHandleMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String newMessage = intent.getExtras().getString(EXTRA_MESSAGE);

    WakeLock.acquire(getApplicationContext());



    // Showing received message
    lblMessage.append(newMessage + "\n");
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "New Message: " + newMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    // Releasing wake lock
    WakeLock.release();
}
```

Where am i missing it?

Comment: You are trying to call object (non-static) method as class (static) method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How to acquire the wakelock in broadcastReceiver.?

```
private PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock;  //Declaration of Instance variable.

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    //......Code.....
    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK |PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP 
                       | PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE,"Wake Lock");
    wakeLock.acquire(15*1000);
    //......Code....
}
```

Add permission in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

Comment: Remove your code of wakelock and implement mine and carefully. It will solve your problem.

Comment: This is what i have done:@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    //......Code.....
    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK |PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP 
                       | PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE,"Wake Lock");
    wakeLock.acquire(15*1000);
    //......Code....
 lblMessage.append(newMessage + "\n"); wakelock.release();} still no show

Comment: Have you declared private PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock;  //Declaration of Instance variable.

Comment: Solved it...i had to create an abstract class :"Wakelocker" to handle the line of code:Wakelocker.acquire(getapplicationcontext); Thanks

Comment: @ewom2468...could you please show me the code to do this....I am facing the same issue.